# React Problem with multiple export in Class Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Previously in my Class Component redux connect used to look something like this. This worked without any issues.

```
//File: MyComponent.jsx
    //in below code this.props.selectProducts is not undefined and this works fine
        const mapStateToProps = null;
        const mapActionsToProps = {
            selectProducts
        };
        
        export default connect(
            mapStateToProps,
            mapActionsToProps
        )(MyComponent);
```

After this I had to use this component called [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack#how-to-use) to display the snackbar and I exported this as default instead of the existing redux connect. Now I am facing a issue where the props doesn't exist.

```
const mapStateToProps = null;
const mapActionsToProps = {
    selectProducts
};

//Now this.props.selectProducts is undefined which is part of redux store
//But this.props.enqueueSnackbar("Preference saved."); this works. which is part of withSnackbar
export const ConnectedList = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapActionsToProps
)(MyComponent);
export default withSnackbar(MyComponent);
```

If i make the redux connect as default I am unable to access this.props.enqueueSnackbar(). Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `withSnackbar` on the component returned by `connect` and use that:

```
const ConnectedList = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapActionsToProps
)(MyComponent);
export default withSnackbar(ConnectedList);
```

Comment: Wow!! Thanks never knew we could do that. I couldn't find the info or may be i didn't know exactly what to search for.